# Function returns Int rather than char

Tags: c, function, return-value

I am working on some practice programs and have run into an issue with my function squeez below.  It is returning an integer rather than a char array as intended.  The code is meant that the user enters, first a character string, followed by a character he wishes to remove.  The squeez function receives both and outputs a string without the given character.

Currently my function gives the warning:
return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

I know the function is returning type 'int' b/c it also displays this 2nd error:
format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]

```
/* Squeeze Function */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char squeez(char s[], int c)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = j = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] != c)
        {
            s[j++] = s[i];
        }
    printf("%c %d", s[i], c);
    }
    printf("%s", s);
    s[j] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i, c;
    char str[10];

    for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; ++i)
    {
        str[i] = c;
    } 
    c = getchar();
    printf("%s", squeez(str, c));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the return type to `char *`:

```
char *squeez(char s[], int c) {
    …
    return s;
}
```

… because `s` is a pointer (the address of the first character of the string).

---

A second problem is that `squeez()` looks for a `'\0'` terminator, but you never wrote one there.  A third problem is that you might overflow the 10-byte buffer.  The loop in `main()` should look more like

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char str[10];

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(str) - 1; i++)
    {
        if ((str[i] = getchar()) == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    assert( (i == sizeof(str) - 1) || (str[i] == '\n') );
    str[i] = '\0';
    printf("%s", squeez(str, getchar()));
}
```

Comment: could you briefly explain the difference.

Comment: When you say return s the compiler will return the pointer to the string s but not the string itself. but your function is expecting a return type of char so it converts the char pointer to a char. Changing the return type will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually returning a char pointer. So the return type of the function should be `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the character pointer. Change the returning `char` to `char *`.

If you are using the char then that will taken as a single character. So when you are using the `char` you are able to return the character only. like this.

```
return s[0]; or else a character variable.
```